# Saving a Json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a button created by canvas i want to save it's value in a json file. After saving the value in a json file, i want when i load my file again, my chosen buttons to give me by default a sunken effect so i can unselect them and select them whenever i can.
How can i give my chosen buttons a sunken effect when i load my json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest is to use a `dict` to save them,
Some changes:

1. I revised your variable `toggle=('sunken', 'flat')` to `toggle=('flat', 'sunken')`,because the value could use index,`False == 0`,`True == 1`.
2. Due to json couldn't use a integer as the key.So I use a char.(To avoid `eval()` or `exec()`)
3. When read the json file,it will refer to the `number_canvas_map` to get the value of corresponding canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
import json
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Intialization')


def press(canvas, button_id, toggle=('flat', 'sunken')):
    global selected_value
    # if the original value is True, change it to False.Vice versa
    selected_value[button_id] = not selected_value[button_id]

    # use the index to set the relief False == 0,True == 1.
    canvas.configure(relief=toggle[selected_value[button_id]])
    print(selected_value)


def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)


def check():
    global selected_value
    data = {}
    path = askdirectory()
    data['buttons'] = selected_value
    writeToJSONFile(path, 'json', data)


def w():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.title('Main')
    global selected_value
    canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width=30, height=20, borderwidth=1)
    buttonBG5 = canvas1.create_rectangle(0, 0, 30, 20, outline="", activefill="#F1F1F1")
    buttonTXT5 = canvas1.create_text((15, 10), text="1", font=("Calibri", 8))
    canvas1.tag_bind(buttonBG5, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas1, "1"))
    canvas1.tag_bind(buttonTXT5, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas1, "1"))
    canvas1.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky='n')
    canvas4 = tk.Canvas(window, width=30, height=20, borderwidth=1)
    buttonBG6 = canvas4.create_rectangle(0, 0, 30, 20, outline="", activefill="#F1F1F1")
    buttonTXT6 = canvas4.create_text((15, 10), text="4", font=("Calibri", 8))
    canvas4.tag_bind(buttonBG6, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas4, "4"))
    canvas4.tag_bind(buttonTXT6, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas4, "4"))
    canvas4.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky='w')
    canvas3 = tk.Canvas(window, width=30, height=20, borderwidth=1)
    buttonBG7 = canvas3.create_rectangle(0, 0, 30, 20, outline="", activefill="#F1F1F1")
    buttonTXT7 = canvas3.create_text((15, 10), text="3", font=("Calibri", 8))
    canvas3.tag_bind(buttonBG7, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas3, "3"))
    canvas3.tag_bind(buttonTXT7, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas3, "3"))
    canvas3.grid(column=3, row=2, padx=10)
    canvas2 = tk.Canvas(window, width=30, height=20, borderwidth=1)
    buttonBG8 = canvas2.create_rectangle(0, 0, 30, 20, outline="", activefill="#F1F1F1")
    buttonTXT8 = canvas2.create_text((15, 10), text="2", font=("Calibri", 8))
    canvas2.tag_bind(buttonBG8, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas2, "2"))
    canvas2.tag_bind(buttonTXT8, "<ButtonPress-1>", lambda x: press(canvas2, "2"))
    canvas2.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky='w')
    save_config = tk.Button(window, text="Save Configuration", bg='green', command=lambda: check())
    save_config.grid(column=0, row=3, pady=10)
    try:
        number_canvas_map = {
            "1": canvas1,
            "2": canvas2,
            "3": canvas3,
            "4": canvas4
        }
        f = open('json.json', "r")
        j = json.loads(f.read())
        selected_value = j['buttons']
        for i in selected_value:
            press(number_canvas_map[i], i)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("No Json File")
    window.grab_set()


load_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Load", command=w)
load_btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
root.mainloop()
```

The json in the file,like(all of them has been pressed at this time):
[image]

---

Ps:If you use OOP,it would avoid using global variable.

Comment: It gives me a Key error whenever i press one of the buttons

Comment: @algorithmical That's because your previous format.You should change the json in the file.Maybe `{"buttons": {"1": false, "2": false, "3": false, "4": false}}`.